# Stop javascript timer from running in background

Tags: javascript

i am having an issue while creating a JS timer. When the time end or is manually stopped, the function keep executing `seconds--`, so even if the time is reset, when started again it starts running at double the speed. How do i manually stop a function? I tried to label it and to use `break label;` without much success. Here is my code

HTML

```
<div id="clock-form">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <input type="number" step="10" id="time-minutes" class="time" value="30"><div id="clock-time"></div></div>
        <div id="clock-buttons">
        <button id="play-button" type="submit" name="play"><i class="fa fa-play clock-buttons" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <button id="stop-button" type="submit" name="stop"><i class="fa fa-stop clock-buttons" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
```

JS

```
    window.onload = function() {

    if(getCookie("date2")) {
        startCountdown();
    }

    var inputMinutes = document.getElementById("minutes");

    var startButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
    startButton.onclick = function() {
        startCountdown();
    }

    stopButton = document.getElementById("stop-button");
    stopButton.onclick = function() {
        delete_cookie("date2");
        clearInterval("intervalHandle");
        document.getElementById("clock-time").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("time-minutes").style.display = "inline";
        // Stop here?   
    }
}

function startCountdown() {
    var minutes = document.getElementById("time-minutes").value;

    if(isNaN(minutes)) {
        alert("Por favor, inserir um número");
        return;
    }
        var dateNow = Math.floor(new Date());

    if(!getCookie("date2")) {
        var dateEnd = (dateNow + (minutes * 60000));
    } else {
        var dateEnd = getCookie("date2");
    }   

    document.cookie = "date2="+dateEnd;

    secondsRemaining = Math.floor((dateEnd - dateNow) / 1000);

    intervalHandle = setInterval(tick, 1000);

    document.getElementById("time-minutes").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("clock-time").style.display = "inline";
}


function tick() {
    var timeDisplay = document.getElementById("clock-time");
    var min = Math.floor(secondsRemaining / 60);
    var sec = secondsRemaining - (min * 60);

    if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }

    var message = min + ":" + sec;
    timeDisplay.innerHTML = "<div style=\"display:inline-block; font-family: 'Open Sans'; font-size:0.9em; font-weight: bold;\">" + message + "</div>";

    if(secondsRemaining === 0) {
        alert("Time's over");
        clearInterval("intervalHandle");
        document.getElementById("clock-time").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("time-minutes").style.display = "inline";
        delete_cookie("date2");
        // Stop here?
}

    secondsRemaining--;
}
```

I have omitted functions regarding the cookies. Thanks a lot everybody!

Comment: `clearInterval("intervalHandle");` that shouldn't be taking a string. It should take the value returned by `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to stopping the code that is running on the interval, simply call `clearInterval(intervalHandle)`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

I could be totally wrong, but I don't think you want to pass the variable to clearInterval as a string.  Instead of calling `clearInterval("intervalHandle")` call `clearInterval(intervalHandle)`

Comment: Not exactly, i can clear the interval. The problem is that after i start the interval again, `seconds--` is executed again so it runs every half second. To make you understand, if i press play 20 times the times goes incredibly fast

Comment: @sky_io That's because you're NOT actually clearing the interval, you just think you are.

Comment: @skY_io - just to check, why don't you add a console.log('test') inside of your "tick" function.  Then when you run it, you'll see it logging out test, test, test, etc.  When you click stop if you are in fact clearing the interval, the logging will stop. - if it continues, you are not clearing the interval.

Comment: @skY_io - no problem glad to help.  If this solves your problem please remember to accept as correct so others know how you resolved the problem.

Comment: I did several tests, everything works perfectly. I don't know how I didn't think about it, at least I have to say I am a novice. Thanks really Phil!

Comment: Yes, I will accept now. I already tried but i got to know that there is a minimum time before being able to accept :D

Comment: @skY_io - everyone starts out as novice, part of the learning process.  I am still VERY notice in many areas.  Glad I could help you.